# Code to monitor server for new files

Tags: windows

Anybody have some code to monitor a windows server and notify me when a new file has been copied to it.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: my answer relates to .Net, what are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you want FileSystemWatcher

msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

example
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6165137.html

EDIT : .Net specific answer

Comment: file system watcher has in WIN32 too;) but it has some Tips you should know about it see http://weblogs.asp.net/ashben/archive/2003/10/14/31773.aspx